# Statistical technique to assess nutrition

Tags: logistic, factor-analysis, biostatistics, discriminant-analysis, correspondence-analysis

My goal is to find risk factors for a disease. I think that a `malnutrition` is a risk factor for this disease.

I have 5 variables that indicate the frequencies of eaten meals (lets say per a fixed period, e.g. every month).

I put the variables in a logistic regression model, but none of them was significant. 
My question is:

What kind of statistical technique I can use to assign a score for every individual that assess his nutrition? factor analysis? correspondence analysis? discriminant analysis?

Can this aproach help finding a "hidden" relationship between the dependent variable and the nutrition score abtained (via logistic regression for example)

Thank you in advance for your help